# SKPhysicsBody containment test?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Any simple method to test if an SKPhysicsBody **entirely contains another**?

Something like `bodyA` contains every point of `bodyB`, or so.

Just wanted to ask you before implement some 2D math helpers to do this with additional "meta"-CGPaths attached to a given node or something.

Comment: The contact delegate will let you know whether two bodies are in contact. You can make two bodies generate contact events without collision feedback through the category etc bitmasks.

Comment: True, but I want to know if one body **entirely contains another**. There must be a math term for this which I don`t know. bodyA contains every point of bodyB, you know.

Comment: testing two rect or two circle bodies for containment is simple but any other shape or combinations thereof are non-trivial - which one are you looking for ie what shapes do you work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a category for this.

```
BOOL putInto = [bodyA containsBody:bodyB];
```

Get the category [**`SKPhysicsBody+Containment from GitHub`**](https://github.com/eppz/labs-physicsBody), it works only for path-path containment for now, gonna finish it up soon for circles as well.

The solution is two fold.

The first part is **`CGPath` works**. You get `CGPathRef` representation of `bodyA` transformed state, then iterate over each point of the `bodyB`, and test for containment. This works fine for path-path type tests, but not for circle-circle, and even less for circle-path.

The second part is to wrap this up into an **`SKPhysicsBody` category**, to encapsulate all the implementation details. This is surprisingly pauinful.

When you ask for an `SKPhysicsBody` instance from `SKPhysicsBody` class, you'd expect an `SKPhysicsBody` object in return. According to some design decision at Apple, it will spit you up a [`PKPhysicsBody`](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS7-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework/PKPhysicsBody.h)instance (part of internal [PhysicsKit](https://github.com/EthanArbuckle/IOS-7-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework)), which of course won't have any instance method from the category you made for `SKPhysicsBody`. Extending that class can be carried out only via method / property swizzlings, so this issue put a weight on this containment category.

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward method, but there are some that you may find useful. If your bodies are rectangular and match their nodes' frames, this might be worth trying:

```
BOOL isContained = CGRectContainsRect(bodyA.node.frame, bodyB.node.frame); // bodyA is the container, bodyB is examined for being contained
```

If your bodies are polygons created with completely arbitrary paths, then finding their containment is going to be a complex task. It's a long shot, but you may get some initial approximation using the above method combined with `CGPathGetBoundingBox` - that will return rectangles around your polygons, which you can then check for overlapping (use `CGRectInset` as needed).

There is also an SKPhysicsWorld method that comes close: `-(SKPhysicsBody *)bodyInRect:(CGRect)rect`, yet it only returns an SKPhysicsBody that intersects a rectangle.

Comment: Horizontal bounding boxes are fairly inaccurate for this, I can really only approx with those.

Comment: I'll create meta path description for each body, needs to be rotated, and check each points against that path if contains. I just wanted to do it simplier.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is super old but it's 2017 and I was searching for an answer and ended up finding my own by tinkering with my code. Hopefully this helps someone out! It works with circles and ovals.

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {

// get the path of the physics body ( contact bodyA )
CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(contact.bodyA.node.position.x - contact.bodyA.node.frame.size.width/2, contact.bodyA.node.position.y - contact.bodyA.node.frame.size.height/2, contact.bodyA.node.frame.size.width, contact.bodyA.node.frame.size.height), nil);

// check if that path contains the physics body point of BodyB
if (CGPathContainsPoint(path, NULL, contact.bodyB.node.position, FALSE)) {

    NSLog(@"CONTAINS POINT player body B");

}
```

}`

Comment: You may consider contributing to this [SKPhysicsBody+Containment](https://github.com/eppz/iOS.Labs.physicsBody) category. You could extend this [containsBody:](https://github.com/eppz/iOS.Labs.physicsBody/blob/master/PhysicsBody/SKPhysicsBody%2BContainment.m#L206) method.